# How to install ruby-augeas gem? (ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, augeas

```
root@ubuntu10:~# gem install ruby-augeas
Fetching: ruby-augeas-0.5.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-augeas:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
    --with-augeas-config
    --without-augeas-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
extconf.rb:27:in `<main>': augeas-devel not installed (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ruby-augeas-0.5.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ruby-augeas-0.5.0/ext/augeas/gem_make.out


No idea what lib is missing....


root@ubuntu10:~# apt-get install libaugeas-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libaugeas-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 108 not upgraded.
```

I have also installed the libaugeas-dev lib , it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `gem` to install `ruby-augeas` on Ubuntu, it's packaged, so just use:

```
sudo apt-get install libaugeas-ruby
```

If you want up-to-date versions of Augeas and ruby-augeas, you can use [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~raphink/+archive/augeas):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:raphink/augeas
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libaugeas-ruby
```

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu 12.04. I fixed it with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

As per following reply: http://www.redhat.com/archives/augeas-devel/2009-August/msg00061.html

Answer (score 5):

`augeas-devel not installed (RuntimeError)`

You should install it :

`sudo apt-get install libaugeas-dev`

Comment: Yet this is what the error you're getting means. You might have a problem with your include paths.

Comment: That said, on Ubuntu, you don't need to use `gem` to install `ruby-augeas` as it's packaged, simply use `sudo apt-get install libaugeas-ruby`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try `gem install ruby-augeas --pre`